# How can I add a mask to a ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way of add a Mask in a ComboBox? I want to add the telephone formatting in my ComboBox, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's a example of a mask in Textfields
[image]

I basically want this, but in a ComboBox.

Comment: Editable `ComboBox`?

Comment: Which part of that? Also is it actually some kind of custom popup that you want (similar to `DatePicker` or `ColorPicker`)? Do you want to display all this info for every item in the the popup? Please provide this info by [edit]ing the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `ComboBox's` `CellFactory`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox<PhoneInfo> comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox .setCellFactory((ListView<PhoneInfo> l) -> new ListCell<PhoneInfo>() {
            TextField tf1 = new TextField();
            TextField tf2 = new TextField();
            TextField tf3 = new TextField();
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            {
                root.add(new Label("Phone Number: "), 0, 0);
                root.add(new Label("Extension: "), 0, 1);
                root.add(new Label("SSN: "), 0, 2);
                root.add(tf1, 1, 0);
                root.add(tf2, 1, 1);
                root.add(tf3, 1, 2);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(PhoneInfo item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    tf1.setText(item.getNumber());
                    tf2.setText(item.getExtension());
                    tf3.setText(item.getSsn());

                    setGraphic(root);
                }
            }
        });

        PhoneInfo phoneInfo = new PhoneInfo("555-555-555", "3333", "444-44-4444");
        comboBox.getItems().add(phoneInfo);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(comboBox)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static class PhoneInfo {

        private String number;
        private String extension;
        private String ssn;

        public PhoneInfo(String number, String extension, String ssn) {
            this.number = number;
            this.extension = extension;
            this.ssn = ssn;
        }

        public String getSsn() {
            return ssn;
        }

        public void setSsn(String ssn) {
            this.ssn = ssn;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getExtension() {
            return extension;
        }

        public void setExtension(String extension) {
            this.extension = extension;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("PhoneInfo{number=").append(number);
            sb.append(", extension=").append(extension);
            sb.append(", ssn=").append(ssn);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }       
    }
}
```

[image]